# Взаимодействие между canvas

Tags: javascript, html, разработка-игр, canvas

Имеются два объекта: игрок и враг.

В случае столкновения двух объектов у объекта "игрок" должна отнимается 1 ед. здоровья.

Но вместо 1 отнимается 8.

```
for (var i = 0; i < enemies.length; i++) {
    if (this.drawY >= enemies[i].drawY
        && this.drawX >= enemies[i].drawX
        && this.drawX <= enemies[i].drawX + enemies[i].width
        && this.drawY <= enemies[i].drawY + enemies[i].height) {
            health--;
        }
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Приведенный код ошибки не содержит, ошибка скорее всего в частоте вызова этой функции, за время одного столкновения она отрабатывает 8 раз

Comment: @yolosora, в консоли ошибок нет...

Comment: И не должно быть никаких ошибок в консоли, это ошибка логики. выводите при декрименте здоровья например текущее здоровье и номер врага в консоль

Comment: @yolosora, проблема решилась.
Враг проходил через игрока и пока два объекта друг на друге оно и вычетало здоровье.

Поставил перед health--
enemies.splice(enemies.indexOf(this), 1);

Comment: А нет, оно удаляет несколько объектов...

Comment: Естественно удаляет)

Comment: А вот так только нужный =)
enemies.splice(enemies.indexOf(enemies[i]), 1);